# Can I use uppercase in Joomla 4 url paths?

Tags: joomla-4.x, url, router

In Joomla 3 it was possible to use an URL of this form `example.com/Essays/somethin-else` because the router would match `'Essays'` to the alias of an existing menu item (eg. 'essays, content, single article) even though aliases are always lower-case.

However in Joomla 4 it appears that the Siterouter `parseSefRoute` rule does not force a lowercase comparison, and so it doesn't match the segment /Essays/ to the menu alias `'essays'` and a 404 error results

We can get round this by doing a redirect in the htaccess file to go to a url (eg. `redirect 301 'example.com/Essays/foo' 'example.com/essays/foo'`)  but that would likely result in changing our pagerank which we would prefer to avoid.

Even were we to write a component, it seems that J4 would not ever accept uppercase in the first segment after the domain name and so our component would never be activated.

I am asking if there is an alternative approach that will allow us to use Joomla 4 with the original URLs but without having to do a redirect.

Thanks!

Comment: You appear to have done your research well and determined that core process will only parse lowercase letters in Joomla 4 and you have provided a workable solution with the .htaccess statements. Is your question that you want an alternative solution to your .htaccess modification? StackExchange is particular in that your Question should be clear in what you are asking for so that people can properly answer. `Any Thoughts?` and `Any suggestions on this?` are ambiguous and not really clear about what type of assistance you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, I am asking if there is an alternative approach that will allow us to use Joomla 4 with the original URLs but without having to do a redirect.

Comment: I edited the original to include a more specific request for assistance

Comment: For com_content or any of the core features using the standard SEF router I would think there isn't anything you can do to change the default behaviour. By the same reasoning any content it is generating to search engine crawlers would also be adhering to lowercase lettering so your search results are probably already affected if they were going to be. Are you concerned about Bookmarks or External links that have been saved with an uppercase letter? What sort of volume of potential candidates are you dealing with here?

Comment: I don't think there is anything we can do other than redirect our incoming links to their lowercase equivalents in htaccess. There is an open GitHub issue on this (https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/38257) and I imagine this will surface a solution at some point in Joomla 4 or 5. We have several thousand legacy articles that will be affected and we are not sure if their pagerank will take a hit by redirecting their upper case links.

Comment: Given the PR has been open for nearly 18 months and Option #1 suggests a more graceful handling of the existing links and yet nothing has been really moved on the issue then I wouldn't be feeling too confident on a solution being implemented by the time you need it. I hope your new comments in the PR prompt some renewed interested and movement in resolving the issue. I would also suggest you research how much of a hit your page ranking is really going to take if you go from Upper to lowercase in your URL. Maybe it is not that big an issue to redirect with .htaccess

Comment: You seem to be familiar with PHP, in which case you can write a plugin to change router's behavior. See https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/32271/12652 for example.

Comment: Thanks to those of you who replied here in the comments! We bit thebullet redirecting URL's to lower case ones. Then we found that the new com_component router causes a 404 if the path part of the url doesn't begin with a digit (I imagine that this is the router in the system merging in the router in the component and then throwing an error on finding an id of zero perhaps) - we considered using the 'noid' option but that would break a bunch of other incoming links. we're still considering the plugin option. Again, thanks!